# Contact form is sending email but not responding after submission.

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have my contact form set where after submitting it redirects back to my homepage but for some reason it just stays on the same page. I'm trying to receive confirmation after email is sent and then a redirect back to my homepage. I'm using php and javascript...........................................

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <h3>Send me a message</h3>
    <form role="form" id="contactForm" action="index2.php" method="POST">
     <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="name" class="h4">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="email" class="h4">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="h4 ">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" 
placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg 
pull-right ">Submit</button>
<div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">Message Submitted!</div>
   </form>
```

index2.php

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://myurl.com/" />


</header>

<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$EmailTo = "arash281pro@live.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
echo "invalid";
}
?>
```

js

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event){
// cancels the form submission
event.preventDefault();
submitForm();
});

function submitForm(){
// Initiate Variables With Form Content
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index2.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){

            formSuccess();
        }
    }
});
}
function formSuccess(){

$( "#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
}

var confirmSubmit = true;

$('form').submit(function(e) {
  if (confirmSubmit) {
   e.stopPropagation();

if (confirm('Are you sure you want to send this form?')) {
  confirmSubmit = false;

  $('form').submit();
}else{
  alert("The form was not submitted.");
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any code that is actually redirecting you hack to your homepage; your `<meta>` refresh in `index2` won't trigger.

Comment: Why have you complicated your stuff? To make your web app fully functional on majority of the browsers and users, keep JS use to minimum. What you are trying can easily be done with lesser and simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually redirecting back to your homepage.
For that you'll need to add something like this after your submit function:

`window.location.replace("index2.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://myurl.com/" />` in index2.php, just add `header("Location: http://myurl.com/");` at the end of the script instead of "success" or "invalid" message. Also remove any HTML before the PHP code starts to prevent errors like "Headers already sent, output started on line ..."

Comment: what is "Location"? I added the code in substitute of success or invalid and it didn't change anything?

Comment: "Location" is an HTTP header instructing the browser to open the provided URL. It can be sent as a response to earlier request - in your case, the POST request that contains the data for email. You can find more details at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location